# How to get the index of button in function when I click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" onclick="delCartItem(3)">
Delete
</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" onclick="delCartItem(3)">
Delete
</button>
...so on
```

I'm making the button which can delete the shopping cart item.

And the parameter of `delCartItem()` is product id.

How to get the index of button when I click one of the button in `delCartItem()` function?

> Supplement:

This is my purpose:

When I click the button => get the index of button
=> use `$('.item_price').eq(idx).text()` get the price of shopping cart item

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 項目 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 商品編號 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 商品名稱 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 存貨量 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 原價 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 數量 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 小計 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 操作 </strong></h3></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>用mBlock玩Arduino - Starting from Scratch</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="item_price">300</td>
        <td>
            <select name="cnt_item[]" class="selectpicker cnt_item" data-width="fit" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true"></select>
        </td>
        <td class="item_total_price">300</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" id='item1' onclick="delCartItem(this.id, 2)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> 刪除 </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>深入淺出程式設計</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td class="item_price">578</td>
        <td>
            <select name="cnt_item[]" class="selectpicker cnt_item" data-width="fit" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true"></select>
        </td>
        <td class="item_total_price">578</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" id='item0' onclick="delCartItem(this.id, 1)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> 刪除 </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Use `$("button.delCartItem").index()`.

Comment: I don't think u should get button index to determine the product to delete.When building these buttons,you should also build the full script when button is clicked.Maybe like this onclick="delCartItem(3,0)",second argument is just the index.determine it when building,not when using.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you call the "index" of the button. Do you mean its position in the list of all similar buttons on the page?

Comment: @Mohammad: It doesn't work :( Thank you!

Comment: Can you maybe provide us your complete table?

Comment: @gumingfeng: Thank you! 
But I need to get the price of product in another `<td>`, use the price(what I total buy) in cookie minus the price which I want to delete from my shopping list

Comment: @Roque: Sorry, What I mean is the position in the`row` of all shopping list.

Comment: I think u can find the Product row by productId,not the index. Something like <tr data-productid='xxx'>,and find by $('tr[data-productid=xxx]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edited]

This should work.

```js
$(".delCartItem").on("click", function(){
  
  var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  
  var price = $tr.find(".item_price").text();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
  var index = $("tr", $tr.closest("table")).index($tr) 
  
  alert("clicked btn in rom: "+ index);
  
  //delCartItem(index);

});





function delCartItem(i){
  //alert("deleting item "+i);
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 項目 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 商品編號 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 商品名稱 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 存貨量 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 原價 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 數量 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 小計 </strong></h3></th>
    <th>
        <h3><strong> 操作 </strong></h3></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>用mBlock玩Arduino - Starting from Scratch</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="item_price">300</td>
        <td>
            <select name="cnt_item[]" class="selectpicker cnt_item" data-width="fit" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true"></select>
        </td>
        <td class="item_total_price">300</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" id='item1' onclick="delCartItem(this.id, 2)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> 刪除 </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>深入淺出程式設計</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td class="item_price">578</td>
        <td>
            <select name="cnt_item[]" class="selectpicker cnt_item" data-width="fit" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true"></select>
        </td>
        <td class="item_total_price">578</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" id='item0' onclick="delCartItem(this.id, 1)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> 刪除 </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But how to pass the item's product id?
I want to use the product id to delete item in cookie

Comment: where are the product ids?

Comment: Sorry, I supplement my table!
Product ID is in another `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of a `data-*` attribute on your button elements to reference the item ids and to create the click handlers programmatically to ease the retrieval of the indexes of the buttons.

```js
$("#the-table .btn").each(function(index, button){
  $(button).on("click", function(){
    var itemId = $(button).data("item-id");
    console.log("button index:", index);
    console.log("item id:", itemId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="the-table">
  <tbody>
    <td class="item_price">578</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" data-item-id="1"> Delete </button>
    </td>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <td class="item_price">608</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning delCartItem" data-item-id="2"> Delete </button>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But `cocoseis` provide the way of select price in another `<td>`